# reloading page with jquery with conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code (jQuery).
Basically I want to reload page if there is  input with `#SchoolName` existing but it misses `class="ac_input"`, IF that class is present, do not reload page.
Is this possible?

```
<input type="text" onfocus="showVal(this.value);" value="" id="SchoolName" size="30" maxlength="50" name="SchoolName" autocomplete="off" class="ac_input">

function autocomplete() {
         $("#SchoolName").autocomplete("ajaxFuncs.php",{cacheLength:1,mustMatch:1,extraParams:{getSchoolName:1}});
    };

$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout("autocomplete()", 500);
    // what do i have to add here???
});
```

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
         autocomplete()
    }, 500);

    // what do i have to add here???
    if($('#SchoolName').length && !$('#SchoolName').hasClass('ac_input')){
        console.log('reload');
        location.reload();
    }

});
```

As you requested, we can write the above code in pure JavaScript as below.

```
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        autocomplete()
    }, 500);

    if(document.getElementById('SchoolName') 
       && document.getElementById('SchoolName').className != 'ac_input'){
        console.log('reload');
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: May be the condition is not satisfied so reload is not happening. I have put a log message in the console, can you check it?

Comment: There is nothing in log, means that the code never got executed :S I don't understand why not :S

What would be normal Javascript code and not jquery?

Comment: You mean the condition or the whole code including `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$('#SchoolName').is('.ac_input'))
    window.location.reload();
```

Comment: This will return `true` if `#SchoolName` does not exist on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Using [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

```
$("#SchoolName:not(.ac_input)").autocomplete("ajaxFuncs.php",{cacheLength:1,mustMatch:1,extraParams:{getSchoolName:1}});
```